# How to detect changes in TinyMCE?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I added TinyMCE(version 4.0.2) editor in a existing HTML form in my project(PHP,Codeigniter). My final target is to enable the form submit button if any changes occur in the form including TinyMCE editor. I can do it only with the form except TinyMCE editor. I could not detect TinyMCE changes.

I want to detect if any change occur when key up. I have seen that tinymce has an onchange function like bellow.

```
            setup : function(ed) {
            ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + l.content);
            });
```

I putted upper setup code inside the bellow init function, but no output i have found.

```
tinymce.init({ });
```

Can you tell how to detect change, or any better idea?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For Tinymce 4  it works for me,

```
        editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
            alert('keyup occured');
            //console.log('init event', e);
            console.log('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + editor.getContent());
            check_submit(); //another function calling
        });
```

### EDIT:

Note that keyup **won't** capture all cases. for example `copy`/`paste`/`cut` from `menu` and not from `keyboard`

if you want you can capture those with

```
editor.on('paste', function(e) {
                    console.debug('paste event');

                });

editor.on('cut', function(e) {
                    console.debug('cut event');

                });
```

**NOTE**
if you capture `cut` and `paste` from tinymce you should probably not process those event from keyup. What I did is to do save only if the keys are not keys for `cut` & `paste` i.e :

```
 /**
 * MCE keyup callback, update the master model selected attribute
 * 
 * @method tinyMCEKeyup
 */
 tinyMCEKeyUp : function(e) {
        console.log('tinymce:keyup');


         var ctrlDown = false;
         var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, xKey = 88;


         if ((e.ctrlKey) && (e.keyCode === vKey)) {
             console.log('paste from keyboard')
             /* got here. do nothing. let paste event handle this one  */
             return;
         } else if ((e.ctrlKey) && (e.keyCode === xKey)) {
             console.log('cut from keyboard')
             /* got here. do nothing. let paste event handle this one  */
             return;
         }

         this.doSave();

},
```

and call this function from the keyup event. This way you will save yourself do some actions twice on cut & paste

**NOTE** soon you will figure out that any `style changes` that happens from `menu` will **NOT** trigger those event as well..

I'm still looking for an answer to capture style change.

Comment: @Rooster242 editor is `setup` argument like `setup : function(editor) {}`

Comment: It didn't occur to me to check for pasting.  Thank you!

Comment: "change" should handle any style changes.  "input" will handle any user edits with the keyboard.

Answer (score 75):

I'm late to the party, but for future reference here is how you do it in TinyMCE 4.X:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   setup:function(ed) {
       ed.on('change', function(e) {
           console.log('the event object ', e);
           console.log('the editor object ', ed);
           console.log('the content ', ed.getContent());
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: note that change event will fire only when editor has lost focus ( for write changes) . this should be combine with the next answer. in order to capture format/drag & drop change

Comment: Note that 'change' fires twice during a "session". Once when you press your first key after you have entered the edit field and once after you leave a changed field.

Answer (score 29):

```
let editorChangeHandlerId;
tinymce.init({
    // ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('Paste Change input Undo Redo', function () {
            clearTimeout(editorChangeHandlerId);
            editorChangeHandlerId = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('changed');
            }, 100);
        });
    }
    // ,...
});
```

Comment: Pay attention to this answer, folks. This is probably the best one. It's the only one that truly raises an event immediately when any change is made.

Comment: The problem is that if you want to do something just once, when any kind of input is made ( be it writing, removing, inserting media, etc), this will trigger it multiple times  based on the type of event that fits the action. For example, if you have an initial state, and add another word, change + input are both fired, then if you click outside of the box, change is fired again, input gets triggered on every character and so on. I would like an input event but for any kind of input

Comment: @Petru Lebada Yes, it would be true, but the timeout function sucks other events because they probably came in 100ms. So your event handler code (in this example the "console.log") runs only once.

Comment: Tried with a timeout but it still triggers all of them

Comment: @Petru Lebada Didn't you declare "editorChangeHandlerId" variable that the setTimeout gives back locally inside the handler function? I modified the snippet to be more clear that the editorChangeHandlerId must be declared somewhere outside.

Comment: @PetruLebada how about caching the previous value? 

```let content;
tinymce.init({
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('Paste Change input Undo Redo', function () {
                 const latestContent= editor.getContent();
                        if (content!== latestContentl) {
                         content = latestContentl;
                         console.log('changed');
                        }
        });
    }
    // ,...
});```

Comment: just add keyup as well then it will truly be onchange.

Comment: This work for me in all cases. thanks man!

Comment: I think you will also need to add `keyup` to handle some special cases with iPad virtual keyboards and to avoid the 100ms latency, you could add some implementation of `throttle` algorithm. It still makes sense to emit your own "changed" event after `setTimeout(..., 0)` to allow the browser native event queue to flush once.

Comment: I think we should remove the input because it will also be triggered on focus.

Answer (score 13):

That works for me:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup : function(ed){
         ed.on('NodeChange', function(e){
             console.log('the event object ' + e);
             console.log('the editor object ' + ed);
             console.log('the content ' + ed.getContent());
         });
    }
});
```

also

```
ed.on('SaveContent', function(e) {
```

or

```
ed.on('submit', function(e) {
```

Found on page http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.Editor in Section Event

Comment: This 'NodeChange' is the only thing that will detect color changes - 4.1.2.

Comment: I 'keyup' and 'NodeChange' and it is working now
ed.on('NodeChange', function(e) {});
ed.on('keyup', function(e) {});

Comment: Well this is useless.  'NodeChange' is firing simply by moving the cursor around in the document.

Answer (score 11):

The following will capture "keyup" and other change events (copy, paste, center, etc.):

```
tinymce.init({
    setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('keyup', function (e) {
            tinyMceChange(ed);
        });
        ed.on('change', function(e) {
            tinyMceChange(ed);
        });
    }
});

function tinyMceChange(ed) {
    console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + ed.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Im using this in tinymce 4.x

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#tinymce-textarea",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on("change", function(e){
            $('#tinymce-livepreview').html(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
        });
        ed.on("keyup", function(){
            $('#tinymce-livepreview').html(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
        });
   }
});
```

**Explanation:**

on("change") is for detect changes on mouse event if u click toolbar icon or selection from the menu. It also able to detect the keyboard event but only after lost focus (not real time).

on("keyup") is for detect changes on real time keyboard event

Answer (score 6):

I'm using TinyMCE 5.4.1

I tried with a lot of events at the same time like '**keyup, copy, paste, cut**' and someones specific for tables like '**newrow**', '**newcell**', but what at the end, the combination what really captures all the changes is 'input NodeChange' ( it covers all the cases of the first events and more )

```
editor.on('input NodeChange', function() {
   console.log('content updated');
});
```

Comment: Works with TinyMCE 6 also

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   setup : function(ed) {
          ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
                  var editorContent = l.content;    // editorContent will hold the values of the editor
                  alert(editorContent);
          });
   }
});
```

CLick for the [Rreference here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onChange)

Comment: I used it, but where to find the result when any change occur. Can you tell me please?

Comment: But when using this code the tinymce editor box disappear. Can you tell please why disappear?

Comment: I tried it, and my editor box disappeared, too - I think it's because onChange is no longer a function in 4.x.  Theoretically, they've replaced it with a similar function named "change", but that's not working for me at all.

Answer (score 2):

We have found that the change event sometimes only fires after pressing enter;  It seems to be tied into the *undo processing*.  Also, the keyup event fires when the contents have not changed, such as when *shift* or *CMD-A* are pressed.

So we use both *change* and *keyup*, and compare the last processed value to the current value to detect a real change.

This solution also works for cut, and paste, and modifications from menu items.

```
//Sometimes does not fire unless enter is pressed
editor.on('change', () => {
    var value = editor.getContent();
    if (value !== editor._lastChange) {
        editor._lastChange = value;
        window.console.log(editor._lastChange);
    }
});

//Sometimes fires even if content did not change
editor.on('keyup', () => {
    var value = editor.getContent();
    if (value !== editor._lastChange) {
        editor._lastChange = value;
        window.console.log(editor._lastChange);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This work fine for me in all condtion **key up , cut, copy , paste**

```
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('KeyUp', function(e){
            alert(editor.getContent());
         });
}
```

Comment: Would be useful if it took care of undo and redo as well since those operations also change ur editor content. Like Nagy Zoltáns answer

Comment: How about copy/cut/paste action via IME or with mouse action which do not use keyboard at all? I think you should use `editor.on('keyup paste change input undo redo', ...)` instead and apply debounce or throttle algorithm to limit excessive events.

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions will not detect whether the tinymce updo button was used.  Unfortunately, neither will this, but it is a little more semantically correct.

```
if (tinymce.activeEditor.isDirty()) {
    alert("Your content is changed.");
}
```

http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:method.tinymce.Editor.isDirty

Answer (score 0):

To detect a form change on the textarea which TinyMCE uses, I am triggering an event on `editor.targetElm`

```
setup: function(editor) {
  editor.on('change', function(e){
    editor.targetElm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  })
},
```

Now I can listen to the event in form validation or other scripts the usual way

```
inputElement.onchange = (e) => {
  // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
    editor.on('write_your_event', function(e) {
      console.log('The ' + e.command + ' command was fired.');
    });
  }
});
```

---

`TinyMCE` supports the following browser-native events:

`beforeinput`, `blur`, `click`, `compositionend`, `compositionstart`, `compositionupdate`, `contextmenu`, `copy`, `cut`, `dblclick`, `drag`, `dragdrop`, `dragend`, `draggesture`, `dragover`, `dragstart`, `drop`, `focus`, `focusin`, `focusout`, `input`, `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`, `mousedown`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mousemove`, `mouseout`, `mouseover`, `mouseup`, `paste`, `reset`, `submit`, `touchcancel`, `touchend`, `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `wheel`.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I've tried using this:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.onChange.add(function() {
        $('#changed').val(1);
    });
}
```

This is to update a hidden field "changed" with the value of 1 so that when a user tries to close pane or leave page they are informed they have unsaved data.

My fault is that this only works if 2 or more changes are made - for example if I noticed I hadn't finished with a full stop "." went back to add this then for some reason clicked close I would be able to leave the page without being warned of the changes